# query count how many records are outside of a date range

Tags: sql

need help with a query to return a count of how many records are outside the date range 1900-01-01 and the current date.

Comment: did you tried something ?

Comment: `select count(*) from tablename where datecolumn not between date'1900-01-01' and current_date`

Comment: Can you give us some info on what you have tried? Which SQL engine are you using? Please also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I am going to be guessing as to the table and field names but this is what you're looking for I believe.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS fieldCount
  FROM myTable
    WHERE dateField NOT BETWEEN '1900-01-01' AND CURRENT DATE
;
```

You can replace CURRENT DATE with whatever works for your SQL engine. CURRENT DATE is for DB2. You can also hard code that for a test query, but that is frowned upon in code and is not dynamic.